# Purpose of enablers

Tags: memory, computers

I was reading the following book:

**But How Do It Know? The Basic Principles of Computers for Everyone**

I learnt that a memory bit ( a special wiring between 4 NAND gates) helps the computer remember the state of a bit (ON/OFF)

I then learnt a Byte is 8 of these memory bits stacked together and this can help the computer remember the state of 8 Bits.

[image]

As I kept reading the concept of enablers ( 8 AND gates stacked together) was introduced and the book said that when the enabler in connected to the output of the byte, it stores 8 bits or a byte.

[image]

I did not understand the purpose of connecting the enabler to a byte because the memory bits in the byte can already remember the state of a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you can store multiple bytes. You don't want all of them driving the same data bus at once, you must enable only one of them to select which byte you are interested in reading in order to use the bits somewhere else.